# Unable To Verify Token On Etherscan

Tags: etherscan

I verified the source code but I emailed Etherscan to update my token logo and web site information and they denied me. They said I don't have a white paper and a visible team members with profile pictures. I literally seen dozens of  tokens that have no official team members or white papers show up on their search with logos and token information. I responded to them saying I don't need to be verified just update my logo and token information and make it come up in search. Having a white paper and team pictures and profiles isn't even a requirement when submitting token information. I don't know what to do now anyone can steal my source code and copy my entire project and make fake profiles and get approved. Since they won't respond to my appeal is there a way to remove the source code from Etherscan? Anyone know what I can do?

Comment: `I literally seen dozens of tokens that have no official team members or white papers show up on their search with logos and token information` - having 100 spoiled apples in the bag doesn't justify adding another one.

Comment: Etherscan is a closed source block explorer. They have total control on what it is shown on their site, and over time they might have changed their policies. Your options are to make a new request to their support or to initiate a legal process.